# Creating database is slow under Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create database by using:

```
create database test;
```

It seems so simple but when I hit enter, it only waits. No error message, just nothing. There is an another database working for a live application, so I can not restart the mysql service. Mysql must be alive all the time. Is there anything I can do about this situation? What is the reason?

Output:

```
root@delta-dbs1:/# mysql -u mysql -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 124011
Server version: 5.1.30-ndb-6.3.20-cluster-gpl MySQL Cluster Server (GPL)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> create database test_wips;
```

and nothing comes after it. It only hangs. And response to ping is also good. There is no problem with network, because my applications are getting data beatifully from the other databases which were created before. My problem is, i cant create or drop any database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the database eventually get created?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the *other application* is slowing down your server with a query. You need to take a look at the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) to check which one.

Answer (score 0):

Please, print console output for

```
$ mysql -u username --password=HIDDEN_PASSWORD --port=330X --host=HOSTNAME
mysql> create database `test`; 
mysql>
```

Maybe your software or network stucks? How do you know that it is exactly MySQL's problem?

You also can try diagnose your network problems using this commands:

```
$ traceroute HOST
$ ping HOST
```

Answer (score -1):

I facing the same above issue.

```
mysql> create database test;
```

(Take too long time to create a database)

Solution:

```
# ps aux | grep ndbd

root        7788  0.0  0.0  24220  4552 ?        Ss   Mar10   0:31 ndbd
root        7789  1.0  9.6 1486868 782376 ?      Sl   Mar10  13:55 ndbd
root       52355  0.0  0.0   6432   656 pts/0    S+   11:53   0:00 grep --color=auto ndbd

# kill -9 7788  7789   -- (Kill the ndbd process because multiple processes running) 

# ndbd  (Once I start ndbd again)
```

database creating command running smoothly.